# Is it possible to receive force stop event in android?

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver

I have created an application running in background using service.
If user will go in

**`Setting---> Application --> Manage Application --> Click on App ---> Click on Force Stop.`**

I want to receive the Force stop event for my application (package).

**How can I do this?**

Here is what I have tried.

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
    String action=arg1.getAction();
    String [] packageNames = arg1.getStringArrayExtra("android.intent.extra.PACKAGES");
    if(packageNames!=null){
        for(String packageName: packageNames){
            Toast.makeText(arg0, "Package name : "+packageName, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            if(packageName!=null && packageName.equals("com.bitgriff.androidcalls")){
                Toast.makeText(arg0, "Package is : "+packageName, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }}
```

This gives me the package name when I click on Manage Application.
But I am getting it only on Android version 2.x.

I want to get Force Stop event for my own application.

Here are the permissions I have added in the menifest file.

```
<receiver android:name="demo.receivers.PackageChangeReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_CHANGED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_INSTALL" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_DATA_CLEARED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_RESTARTED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.DELETE" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUERY_PACKAGE_RESTART" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
                <data android:scheme="package" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.